# Passing an argument to a button's "onclick" in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to pass an argument to a function in javascript dynamically. I tried this :

```
var dsOption = "hello";
x_button.setAttribute("onclick", "xfunc(dsOption)");
```

but it is not working ! How to achieve this?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x_button.setAttribute("onclick", "xfunc("+JSON.stringify(dsOption)+")");
```

You had been just passing the identifier `dsOption`, which also might be evaluated out of context. Here, i pass the *value* of `dsOption`, encoded as a string.

Comment: can you elaborate more upon +JSON.stringify(dsOption)+ what are these + signs here?

Comment: The `+` concatenates the values. That's a fancy computer term for joining strings.
May i recommend that you go learn some more JavaScript?

Comment: ya..got it know..i do know that + concatenates strings, just got confused at the first sight. thnx